# Web3 behaves different on the client and server with different providers

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura, sha3, get-storage-at

I'm trying to read a mapping storage variable from blockchain. Below, are my attempts, from client and server. Testing on Rinkeby network.

**From client:**
Metamask is installed and I'm trying from the browser console. Web3 version is 0.2.x.

```
const index = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005";
const key = web3.toHex('my_key');

web3.eth.getStorageAt(
  'contract_address_here',
   web3.sha3(key + index, { encoding: 'hex' }),
   (err, result) => {
        console.log(result); // Returns 0x00.....1; // Key exists
   }
);
```

It works. The key does exist on the Rinkeby network.

**Attempt from server:**
Please note, that web3 version is `1.0.0-beta.26` and I'm using Infura as the provider.

```
// Init web3
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
  "my rinkeby infura link here"
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider); 

const index = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005";
const key = web3.utils.toHex('my_key');

web3.eth.getStorageAt(
  'contract_address_here',
  web3.utils.sha3(key + index, { encoding: 'hex' }),
  (err, result) => {
    console.log(result); On the server, the result is always 0x...0
  }
);
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? I'm making double sure, the Contract address is the one that is on Rinkeby and also my Infura link is one from Rinkeby.

**Edit:**
1. Looks like the web3 version is the problem. If I try to use web3 0.2.x on the server and hook it up with Infura provider, it works well.

Comment: Your syntax looks broken for both. Are you sure that's the exact code you are/were running?

Comment: Which part of the syntax is broken? I don't see the interpreter throwing any error for either.

Comment: For the web3.js 0.2x.x version, there's a missing curly brace. I also can't get the following syntax to work, but maybe you use a transpiler that understands it? `() => (err, result) {` It seems to me that would be a callback that takes no arguments and returns a function that takes two arguments? (But it's missing a fat arrow if that's the case.)

Comment: There's also a non-comment comment in the 1.0 example, but I assume that was added after you pasted into Stack Exchange.

Comment: I posted the (working) code I ran as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, the missing curly brace is a problem in both snippets.

Comment: I edited the question. It was due to a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing up the syntax, both examples work for me.

Solidity code I used, deployed to `ganache`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Test {
    uint256 a;
    uint256 b;
    uint256 c;
    uint256 d;
    uint256 e;
    mapping (string => bool) exists;

    function Test() public {
        exists["my_key"] = true;
    }
}
```

web3.js 0.2x.x code I used, in the browser with MetaMask pointing at `ganache`:

```
var index = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005";
var key = web3.toHex('my_key');

web3.eth.getStorageAt(
  "0x6d533f202b5bece917de226d7d588480e0ba7c0e",
  web3.sha3(key+index, { encoding: 'hex' }),
  (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

And here's the web3.js 1.0.0-beta code I used, also pointing at `ganache`:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

var index = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005";
var key = web3.utils.toHex('my_key');
web3.eth.getStorageAt(
  "0x6d533f202b5bece917de226d7d588480e0ba7c0e",
  web3.utils.sha3(key+index),
  (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

(The second parameter you have for `web3.utils.sha3` in the 1.0 beta code is harmless but ignored. The code works with or without it. Unlike its 0.2x.x counterpart, `web3.utils.sha3` interprets its first argument as hex if it starts with `0x`.)

**EDIT**

Your key looks like hex already, so `web3.utils.toHex` isn't transforming it the same way `web3.toHex` in 0.2x.x is. You should probably be using `fromAscii` in both cases, assuming you do indeed want to treat the key as a string. This code works with 1.0.0-beta26:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/<key redacted>');

var index = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005";
var key = web3.utils.fromAscii('708d343ff29ab3350d9a9499d7db1cfefc919bce');
web3.eth.getStorageAt(
  "0x670c3ee20d857ECD9A1C6024a2701443C3F7f2e2",
  web3.utils.sha3(key+index),
  (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: No actually. It is not working. I might have made an error while editing syntax, here on the forum.  If it helps, I'm using "web3": "1.0.0-beta.26"

Comment: I fixed the editing. Just to make sure, I double checked the syntax. It still does not work. Could you give it a try from 1.0.0-beta.26 web3?

Comment: I'm on 1.0.0-beta.29. I can try downgrading.

Comment: Same result for me on 1.0.0-beta.26. Perhaps you can share the contract address and key on Rinkeby so I can test against your actual contract.

Comment: Contract address: 0x670c3ee20d857ECD9A1C6024a2701443C3F7f2e2

Key: 708d343ff29ab3350d9a9499d7db1cfefc919bce

Comment: Look at the image here: https://ibb.co/mYSaQ7

Comment: See my edit. You probably could have discovered this by printing out the `key`. :-)

Comment: (You could have also saved us some time by providing the actual key you were using up front instead of `my_key`.)

Comment: Damn! I was receiving the key from some API, which stated it as a string. I did not take the time to see if it was a hex string.

Comment: What if the key keeps varying between a regular string and a hex string?

Comment: I don't know what that means. If you want to treat it as an ASCII string, then use `web3.utils.fromAscii`.